# SharePoint 2013 App Part : Dynamically set values for the tool part panel controls on serverside

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin, app, toolpart

How can I dynamically fill a dropdown list in a Tool Part panel of a SharePoint 2013 app part?

What I want to achieve:

- User checks a checkbox
- Dropdown appears
- The list items in this dropdown are set in the server side i.e. either dependent on user's input for other elements or on the specific user's permissions

Your help is really appreciated! I need to come up with a solution as soon as possible, so any guidance on how to approach this will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure there is a limitation in the app model against doing this. Only basic tool parts / custom properties like string, int, bool or enum can be created in app Webparts

See section Table 2. App part custom properties
here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179921.aspx

Comment: Can we set the enum values dynamically?

Comment: Don't think so since they are declared I the XML file, but I have not investigated that further.

Comment: Okay, I appreciated the App Model quite a bit until this T_T .. I will do more research and if it is absolutely not possible... I will implement what I have to using a Visual Web Part